# Detecting python functions using a regex?

Tags: python, regex

I want to pull out all of the python functions within a python script. Is there any single regex I can use to do this, e.g:

```
import re
all_functions = re.findall(regex, python_script)
```

I have implemented a very cumbersome way of doing this involving many if statements, but I feel there is a more elegant solution with regexes.

I think the regex should be something like this:

```
'def.*?\n\S'
```

because:

1. Functions start with `def`
2. Followed by anything (but we want to be non-greedy)
3. A function ends when after a newline character `\n`, the starting character of the next line is not white space `\S`

However, I can't seem to get this to work over multiple lines.

Edit: Python functions may be contained in files that don't have `.py` extensions; e.g. they can be contained in IPython notebooks with `.ipynb` extension so I can't necessarily always `import` the code and use `dir()`.

Comment: Why not import it as module and look into its contents via `dir` and check their types? If the code is to be trusted of course

Comment: mpcabd, thanks for the suggestion, but I was looking for a solution that would work for all file types, e.g. sometimes there are python functions within IPython notebooks which have .ipynb extensions, so a regex would allow me to get functions out of those file types as well

Comment: `def` can't be followed by *"anything"*, there's a definition for identifiers. Perhaps you should look into Python's grammar? Also, if you want `.` to include line breaks you need `re.DOTALL`.

Comment: jonrsharpe, you are right, the regex should be more specific, perhaps something along the lines of `'def [A-Za-z_][A-Za-z_0-9]*?\(.*?\)'`, assuming only well written python functions are contained in the file, I think that should detect the beginning of functions.

Comment: "1.  Functions start with def".  This is almost entirely untrue.  They can be assigned to variables, synthesized from code objects, built anonymously with `lambda` statements, assigned to keys in the `globals()` dictionary, or appear as if by magic wherever `eval` rears its ugly head... and I'm sure I've missed some.  In general, **you can't use regular expressions to parse a non-regular language** like Python.  Can't be done, except in ridiculously limited circumstances... and even then, only when you already know _exactly_ what you're looking for.

Answer (score 8):

Don't use a regular expression. Have Python parse the code for you and find all the function definitions with the [`ast` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html):

```
import ast

with open(python_sourcefile) as sourcefile:
    tree = ast.parse(sourcefile.read(), sourcefile.name)

for node in ast.walk(tree):
    if isinstance(node, ast.FunctionDef):
        print(node.name)
```

If the code is contained in `.ipynb` files, parse the file and extract the `code` cells, then put the `input` source code from those through the same process.

Demo with the `ast` module source itself:

```
>>> import ast
>>> with open(ast.__file__.rstrip('c')) as sourcefile:
...     tree = ast.parse(sourcefile.read(), sourcefile.name)
... 
>>> for node in ast.walk(tree):
...     if isinstance(node, ast.FunctionDef):
...         print(node.name)
... 
parse
literal_eval
dump
copy_location
fix_missing_locations
increment_lineno
iter_fields
iter_child_nodes
get_docstring
walk
_convert
_format
_fix
visit
generic_visit
generic_visit
```

Comment: Thanks, the ast library looks pretty cool, I will try this out

Answer (score 1):

This regex might work out for you:

`re.compile('def (?P<function>(?P<function_name>.*?)\((?P<function_args>.*)\)):')`

I used groups so you could get information out easily using the groupdict() method of a match object, but if you just want the declaration line, you can use
    `re.compile('def .*?\(.*)\):')`

This regex could be tighter (it'll accept `def do something(1,2,3):` even though it's not a valid function), but if your python files are syntactically correct and you *absolutely* want to use a regex, this'll do the job for you.

Comment: Thanks Akshay, but I am trying to get the entire function not just the function name, so the regex needs to terminate with something like '\n\S' and would need to match multiple lines as well.